# Numbers that are divisible

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

So I am given the following question: For natural numbers less than or equal to 120, how many are divisible by 2, 3, or 5? I solved it by inclusion-exclusion principle and by using the least common multiple by having it as (2, 3, 5)=120 which is equal to 30. Are these the right way to solve them or is there other ways?

Comment: Hint: The probability that a random number in the given range is divisible by $2$ is $50\%$. Also, the three events "a random number in the range is divisible by $2$", "a random number in the range is divisible by $3$" and "a random number in the range is divisible by $5$" are independent.

Answer (score 1):

It is a right way. Inevitably there are others. For example, there are $\varphi(120)$ numbers in the interval $[1,120]$ which are relatively prime to $120$. Here $\varphi$ is the Euler $\varphi$-function.

The numbers in our interval which are divisible by $2$, $3$, or $5$ are precisely the numbers in our interval which are **not** relatively prime to $120$.

So $120-\varphi(120)$ gives the desired count. Compute $\varphi(120)$ by using the usual formula, and the fact that $120=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5$.

The Inclusion/Exclusion procedure is more versatile than the Euler $\phi$-function procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion-exclusion is a good choice (and I expect your teacher intended you to use this method).

However, in mathematics, there are often many methods you can use.  For instance, we could instead find the answer computationally (in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) this can be found by `Number([1..120],i->i mod 2=0 or i mod 3=0 or i mod 5=0);`).

There is no "best" method.  In fact, it's usually best to use multiple methods in order to perform cross-checking.